# Logging all http requests to domain

Tags: nginx, logging, http, apache2

I bought a domain name and I would like to log what http requests it receives. Logging the requests headers, url, type and message body. Looking for an easy/affordable solution. Standing up an Apache or Nginx server with logging turned up seems like a good option. Or using some logging capabilities on cloudflare, aws or gcp.

Thanks!

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/512146/logging-domain-of-http-requests-in-apache  or share why that is not an answer to this question.

Comment: I guess the reason that isn’t the answer is because it’s been about 10 years since that was answered. I am hoping their has been some improvements for this logging capability.

Comment: Why would that change if logging Apache works OK ?

Comment: It is A answer to the question but doesn’t cover all possible use cases. Sometimes it is good to evaluate what has changed in the last 10 years. Apache is good enough but there might be more efficient tools.

Comment: Question is tooo broad, and is missing details, to give **1** correct answer.

Comment: `Apache or Nginx server with logging turned up seems like a good option` you are correct, that is a good option, considering you'd have to set up one of those to serve http requests in the first place.